# ECS Container and Docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I have been stuck on this for the longest now: I am deploying the Python code as a dockerized container.

I am doing all this in Python CDK.

Here is how I am creating the cluster

```
vpc_test = _ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "VPC",
                      vpc_id= "vpc-6****"
                )
    #Setting up the container to run the job
    cluster = _ecs.Cluster(self, "ClusterToGetFile",
                           vpc=vpc_test
                           )
    task_definition = _ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(self, "TaskDefinition",
                                                 cpu=2048,
                                                 memory_limit_mib=4096
                                                 )
    task_definition.add_container("getFileTask",

                           image = _ecs.ContainerImage.from_asset(directory="assets", file="Dockerfile-ecs-file-download"))
```

Here is the - Dockerfile-ecs-file-download

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /usr/app/src
COPY marketo-ecs-get-file/get_ecs_file_marketo.py ./
COPY marketo-ecs-get-file/requirements.txt ./
COPY common_functions ./
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt  --no-cache
CMD ["python" , "./get_ecs_file_marketo.py"]
```

All I am trying to do, to begin with, is to run the task(Deploy) manually.

All I have in the get_ecs_file_marketo.py.py file is

```
import logging
logging.info("ECS Container has stareted. ")
```

However, when I deploy the task, I get this error:

```
Stopped reason
Essential container in task exited
```

My plan is to use the ecs run task as part of a step function. So when Lambda is done processing some data and it needs to do a data pull, it will call the RunTask of this container.

Ideally, I would want to have the Lambda in step function do it all, however, the time limits are causing the lambda to die before the complete file is downloaded and pushed to S3. This will be a regular exercise, however, the lambda upfront is required as the job will need to Enqueue a request, and keep checking for file status before the ecs/container can go and start downloading the file.

Any feedback is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working exactly how I would expect it to. All your script is doing is printing a log message and exiting.

You aren't really getting an error message, you're just being notified that your script stopped running (because it finished).

Comment: However when I go to the cloudwatch there are no logs for the print statements. The logs are completely empty. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes, you are logging an INFO level message, but you haven't enabled INFO output on the logger. By default the Python log level is WARNING. Try just changing it to a `print()` statement for now. Also, you should be able to run the same docker container locally and see exactly the same behavior. I highly suggest getting it to work like you expect locally first, before adding AWS into the mix.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I will try it out.